# How to copy a website from a remote server to local host

Tags: mysql, web, webserver, localhost

I have a website that is running on a server. I want to get it down to my local machine so i can edit it without it being like, this means i'll have to copy the database as well as all the images and HTML, JavaScript, PHP and so on.

My server is running ubuntu server and i am also running ubuntu LAMP on my local machine.

Now i understand that getting all the webpages and images down is simple, just a matter of pulling them down using filezila, but what about the databases?

I know that because its linux everything is stored as a file so would it be a case of be finding the file and copying them to the local machine? If so where would one usually find these files?

thanks a lot for the help, any ideas and tips are more then welcome.

Comment: You need to export your database using the command line

Comment: Or with PhpMyAdmin/similar tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the files, you first have to shut down the database otherwise you could end up with an inconsistent file(s). If the target database is compatible with the file format (eg: same version) this works.

You can dump the databases (with `mysqldump` or a tool like phpmyadmin), and load it on the other machine (`mysql <dump.sql`). If you want to dump a consistent state, again, you have to either shut down the database or temporary disable writes.

Answer (score 0):

This question cannot be answered without knowing a lot more about your website.

It would probably be a safe bet to ask the hosting provider to create a backup of your database for you, one that you can then restore on your local machine.

Comment: Well i have been working on this website for a while and I made the mistake of not starting it on my local machine before uploading it and keeping the copy on my local machine the version that i use to edit before uploading, by doing this i have had a number of narrow misses so i'm planning on pulling it all down from the server to run on my machine and was just wondering if there was a general, automated way of doing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your host support some kind of [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) for example [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [GIT](http://git-scm.com/).

This will allow you to push and pull your code from localhost to your server.

Otherwise, you could use an FTP.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you want to know this.You can check out and follow instructions there.

http://www.landcoder.com/transfer-website-from-live-server-into-localhost-localpc-without-using-plugin-388

If you are not using a wordpress, you can simply go with procedure #1.

Transfer your files from your web server into your localhost

a. Access your files on web server using FTP Filezilla client and,
b. Copy files into your local PC where your local server is located.

example. C:\xampp\htdocs\your-site-name\

On my personal computer, I have installed a XAMPP server, therefore I have saved the files inside the htdocs folder.Note that, you must have installed a local server in your computer, if not, you could not be able to proceed below.